# How to detect right and left click in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I want to create a action on right and left click of mouse. Click may be on NSTableViewCell, NSView, etc (Like when we right click on window it gives a pop-up ) . Is there any API to do such task? If no, any other way .
Thank you in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to override *NSResponder* methods like:

```
- (void) mouseDown: (NSEvent*) theEvent;
- (void) rightMouseDown: (NSEvent*) theEvent;
```

Reference: [NSResponder Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Update: as mentioned below, `NSView` and `NSTableView` inherits these methods from NSResponder.

Answer (score 2):

`NSView` and `NSTableView` inherits from `NSResponder` and `NSResponder` has `rightMouseDown` event, and other mouse events.

Some documentation related to this:

[Introduction to View Programming Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978)

[Cocoa Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i)