# Detect right mouse click on cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mouseevent

I'm trying to manage mouse events in my prototype of **Sprite-kit** game.

I used the following methods from the question [SO_q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473176/how-to-detect-right-and-left-click-in-cocoa)

```
- (void) mouseDown: (NSEvent*) theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"Click!");
}

- (void) rightMouseDown:(NSEvent*) theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"DERECHA PULSADA!");
}
```

But the method to detect the right clic doesn't work for me. I want to detect click and drop of right mouse click.
How can i detect when the mouse click is dropped ?

**UPDATE:**

I tried with the following mehod, picked up from the [Cocoa Event Handling Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6-SW1).

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent 
{
        switch ([theEvent type])
        {
            case NSLeftMouseDown:
                NSLog(@"ISQUIERDO down!");
                break;
            case NSLeftMouseUp:
                NSLog(@"IZQDO soltado!");
                break;
            case RightMouseDown:
                NSLog(@"DERECHO PUSSSHHH!");
                break;
            case NSRightMouseUp:
                NSLog(@"Botón Derecho Soltado!");
                break;
            default:
                /* Ignore any other kind of event. */
                break;
        }

    return;
}
```

*Result*: Only event for the left click has been handled.

Following reading the [Cocoa Event Handling Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6-SW1) i tried overwriting the following methods:

```
-(void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"DERECHO PUSSSHHH!");
}

- (void)rightMouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"Botón Derecho Soltado!");
}
```

Didn't work too.

**UPDATE:**

Like i said before, theses methods are in a Sprite-Kit class. Here the class definition where these methods are defined.

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface OpcionesMenu : SKScene

@end
```

Comment: In what way don't they work? Are they called? Where did you add them? What views do you have in your app?

Comment: The first method works but the method to detect the right click doesn't work. I made a mistake writing the question, I corrected it.

Comment: What does 'the mouse click is dropped' mean?

Comment: mouse click dropped = Mouse button up.

Comment: So where are these methods implemented? Are the clicks being handled by a different view (because they aren't passed up the responder chain)?

Comment: I've added more code i tried but i only achieve to detect event of the left click.

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez: You haven't answered Wain's question. Where in your program did you implement these methods?

Comment: Added the class definition. The methods are in a SKScene which seems to be like a view.

Answer (score 17):

If you look at Apple's documentation for [NSView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) you'll see that NSView's implementation of rightMouseDown: does not send right mouse down events up to the responder chain, but instead handles the event directly by calling `menuForEvent:`.

SKView is a subclass of NSView, so I solved this problem by adding a category to SKView and implementing my own version of `rightMouseDown:`.  My version of rightMouseDown: merely calls my scenes implementation of `rightMouseDown:`, which is where I actually perform actions on my scene.  SKView has a property, scene, which holds a reference to the currently presented scene.  Therefore, my category implementation of rightMouseDown: looks like this:

**ObjC:**

```
@implementation SKView (Right_Mouse)
-(void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
     [self.scene rightMouseDown:theEvent];
}
@end
```

I elaborate on this a bit more on my [blog](http://www.two-tangled-trees.com/1/post/2014/02/right-mouse-down-events-in-sprite-kit.html) if you're interested.

**Swift 3 + iOS10:**

```
extension SKView {
  open override func rightMouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
    self.scene?.rightMouseDown(with: theEvent)
  }
}
```

**Swift:**

```
extension SKView {
    public override func rightMouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {  
        self.scene?.rightMouseDown(theEvent)
    } 
}
```

and add this to your `SKScene` subclass

```
override func rightMouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is great. For anyone else that stumbles upon this, you can simply throw the code above at the top of your `SKScene` implementation and your scene's `rightMouseDown:` will indeed be called.

Comment: How could I do this in swift?

Comment: extension SKView {
    
    public override func rightMouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        self.scene?.rightMouseDown(theEvent)
    }
}

Comment: This extension works, but might not be the best idea, since it permanently disables contextual menus in all SKView subclasses. I've written more about it here: http://extelligentcocoa.org/double-click-and-right-mouse-behaviour/ - you might have to subclass SKView, call super.rightMouseDown, or override menuForEvent, depending on your individual needs.

Comment: Why iOS10 if this is solely a macOS feature?

Answer (score 2):

```
extension SKView {

public override func rightMouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    self.scene?.rightMouseDown(theEvent)
}
```

This works nicely in swift, thanks guys!