# How to catch right mouse button events with my SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, mouseevent, skscene

I've overriden the rightMouseDown(with event:) function, but nothing, even a simple print(), will happen?  Is there anything more I need to do?  The mouseDown() func work properly though...

Any clue?

Comment: Post your code attempt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect right mouse click on cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856059/detect-right-mouse-click-on-cocoa)

Comment: @Nero : Thanks for the pointer!  It sounds like it could be the solution!

Comment: It was the solution!  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

Since the right click is reserved by default for the popup menu, you need to add an extension that will override rightMouseDown() and redirect the event to your scene's event.

Here is the solution I found on another thread and that works (Swift 3)

```
extension SKView {

open override func rightMouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    self.scene?.rightMouseDown(theEvent)
}
```