# How do I respond to two-fingered trackpad clicks? (OSX Xcode Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, mouse, trackpad

In my OSX app, I have to tell the difference between left (primary) click and right (secondary) click and do something different based on which it was. The trouble is, I'm working on my Macbook Pro, meaning I'm using a trackpad during testing, not an actual mouse.

In the view that should respond to clicks, I implemented mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent, but it only triggers when I do a one-fingered click. If I do a two-fingered click, it doesn't trigger at all (I have an NSLog in there so I know when it is or isn't triggering). How can I trigger the mouse down event for a two-fingered (secondary) click on the trackpad? I don't care about gestures or anything, I just want to be able to respond to two-finger clicks, which are the trackpad-version of right clicks.

Comment: Just check this:[Question  and Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473176/how-to-detect-right-and-left-click-in-cocoa)

Comment: Wow, that was disgustingly easy haha. Thanks!